# Hadoop block distribution java class. keeping few blocks on selected datanode

Tags: hadoop

I would like to know, the main java class in Hadoop which distributes the blocks to datanode. How namenode decides on the number of blocks which are going to a datanode. I want to keep first 2 blocks in first datanode, then next 2 in second and so on in first go not using balancer. Can you please comment on this?

I have gone through the hadoop source code. FSNameSystem.java class under namenode is handling the name space management, but it is unclear how it is deciding on number of blocks per datanode.